# CSS file in same folder as HTML not found

Tags: html, css, web, get

This is a really basic problem, but I've somehow been struggling to figure this out for the past week. I just started adding CSS to my project, and linked base_style.css to base.html. For some reason, the server cannot find base_style.css.

Base.html:

```
<head>
    <title> Chat </title>
    <link href = "base_style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">
    
</head>
```

base_style.css:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

However, when I run the server through my command prompt, I get:

```
[21/Aug/2020 23:35:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 517
Not Found: /base_style.css
[21/Aug/2020 23:35:25] "GET /base_style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 5153
```

Even through the base_style.css and base.html are in the same folder/directory:

```
08/18/2020  07:48 PM    <DIR>          .
08/18/2020  07:48 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/21/2020  11:24 PM               584 base.html
08/21/2020  11:24 PM                51 base_style.css
08/17/2020  12:05 AM               622 chatroom.html
08/13/2020  05:03 PM               418 chatrooms.html
08/15/2020  09:53 PM               376 edit_message.html
08/13/2020  05:00 PM               295 index.html
08/13/2020  05:06 PM               272 new_chatroom.html
08/14/2020  04:00 PM               378 new_message.html
               8 File(s)          2,996 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  417,867,866,112 bytes free
```

If anyone knows what's going on, I appreciate any help.

Comment: What server are you running this with?

Comment: I am running this on my command prompt terminal, with just python manage.py runserver, and then opening http://127.0.0.1:8000/ on chrome. I've also tried running this through heroku, which also didn't work (but with no error message)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use relative path:

```html
<link href = "./base_style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">
```

Comment: I tried it out, but I'm still getting the same error: Not Found: /base_style.css

Comment: That answer above does seem correct.  I usually suggest putting the tag in this order <link rel=“stylesheet” href=“./base_style.css”>. I’d try it without the type property and maybe try another browser.

Answer (score 0):

While running app from `server` you need to specify path from `root directory`

If folder structure is like this:  `web-app > public > base_style.css`

then path will be `public/base_style.css`

thus:

```html
<link href=`public/base_style.css` type=`text/css` rel = `stylesheet`>
```

Specify path from your root folder and it will work :)

Comment: the full path from Desktop is: "Desktop/project2/chat/chat_app/templates/chat_app/base_style.css". I've tried: "chat/chat_app/templates/chat_app/base_style.css", "chat_app/templates/chat_app/base_style.css", "templates/chat_app/base_style.css", "chat_app/base_style.css" and none of them work? very confused. I appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: Which folder you are running server from?
In my example `web-app` folder has `server.js` which ups the server

Comment: After I navigate to "Desktop/project2/chat", I run server by entering: "python manage.py runserver" into my command prompt

Answer (score 0):

To add a CSS file in HTML code being called by a server, you have to start the path from the base directory of the project.

It should be something like this:

```
<head>
    <title> Chat </title>
    <link href = "<path from project base dir to current dir>/base_style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">
    
</head>
```

Comment: the full path from Desktop is: "Desktop/project2/chat/chat_app/templates/chat_app/base_style.css". I've tried: "chat/chat_app/templates/chat_app/base_style.css", "chat_app/templates/chat_app/base_style.css", "templates/chat_app/base_style.css", "chat_app/base_style.css" and none of them work? very confused. I appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: Try adding path as "project2/chat/chat_app/templates/chat_app/base_style.css". This should most probably work.